# Running a batch script from UNIX

Tags: batch-file, unix

I have a batch script saved in a network share path. I need my shell script, which runs every one hour to execute this batch script. I searched the forum multiple times and found that we can use `rsh` to start a batch script from UNIX. I further found that the `rsh` requires a Hostname as a parameter. There's my problem, I don't have a machine, I have a network shared path (like `\\abc\defgh\adf.bat`). Is there a way, I can specify a share path (more like a mount point)?

Comment: Why `abc` will not serve as the hostname, if it is successfully resolved by your DNS server?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful - Will it work if I write it like `rsh -l myuid abc "\\abc\defgh\adf.bat"`?

Comment: Try `rsh abc -l myuid "defgh/adf.bat"`, I can't confirm whether that'd work. Make sure that the path `defgh/adf.bat` is resolved successfully from myuid's home directory.